# Jupyter Notebook Not Running Mac OS

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Just installed jupyter notebook through Anaconda and keep getting this error message when trying to run the command in terminal:

```
Last login: Wed Mar  7 16:33:16 on ttys001
dhcp-gs-4010:~ Max$ jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Max/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 11, in <module>
     sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/Max/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 266, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Max/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-    packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 657, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/Users/Max/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-    packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Max/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-    packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1507, in initialize
    self.init_webapp()
  File "/Users/Max/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-    packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1270, in init_webapp
    self.jinja_environment_options
  File "/Users/Max/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-    packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 156, in __init__
    default_url, settings_overrides, jinja_env_options)
  File "/Users/Max/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-    packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 268, in init_settings
    nbextensions_path=jupyter_app.nbextensions_path,
  File "/Users/Max/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-    packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 973, in nbextensions_path
    from IPython.paths import get_ipython_dir
  File "/Users/Max/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-    packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    from .terminal.embed import embed
  File "/Users/Max/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-    packages/IPython/terminal/embed.py", line 16, in <module>
    from IPython.terminal.interactiveshell import     TerminalInteractiveShell
  File "/Users/Max/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-    packages/IPython/terminal/interactiveshell.py", line 32, in <module>
    from .debugger import TerminalPdb, Pdb
  File "/Users/Max/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-    packages/IPython/terminal/debugger.py", line 6, in <module>
    from IPython.core.completer import IPCompleter
  File "/Users/Max/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-    packages/IPython/core/completer.py", line 146, in <module>
    import jedi
  File "/Users/Max/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-    packages/jedi/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from jedi.api import Script, Interpreter, set_debug_function, \
  File "/Users/Max/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-    packages/jedi/api/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from jedi.api import classes
  File "/Users/Max/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-    packages/jedi/api/classes.py", line 13, in <module>
    from jedi.evaluate.utils import ignored, unite
  File "/Users/Max/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-    packages/jedi/evaluate/__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
    from jedi.evaluate.context import ClassContext, FunctionContext, \
  File "/Users/Max/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-    packages/jedi/evaluate/context/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from jedi.evaluate.context.function import FunctionContext,     FunctionExecutionContext
  File "/Users/Max/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-    packages/jedi/evaluate/context/function.py", line 8, in <module>
    from jedi.evaluate import docstrings
  File "/Users/Max/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jedi/evaluate/docstrings.py", line 46, in <module>
    from numpydoc.docscrape import NumpyDocString
  File "/Users/Max/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-    packages/numpydoc/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .numpydoc import setup
  File "/Users/Max/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-    packages/numpydoc/numpydoc.py", line 31, in <module>
    from .docscrape_sphinx import get_doc_object, SphinxDocString
  File "/Users/Max/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-    packages/numpydoc/docscrape_sphinx.py", line 14, in <module>
    from sphinx.jinja2glue import BuiltinTemplateLoader
  File "/Users/Max/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-    packages/sphinx/jinja2glue.py", line 22, in <module>
    from sphinx.application import TemplateBridge
  File "/Users/Max/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sphinx/application.py", line 25, in <module>
    from docutils import nodes
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/docutils/__init__.py", line 68, in <module>
    class ApplicationError(StandardError):
NameError: name 'StandardError' is not defined
```

I've uninstalled and reinstalled a few times but can't seem to figure out why its not working. Any advice is welcome!

Comment: Are you trying to open jupyter using the anaconda navigator? Also you shouldn't have to install jupyter if you installed anaconda, it comes with it. If you are installing it using pip, that could cause problems.

Comment: I see there is a call to python 2.7 in your Traceback. Have you tried uninstalling it, running jupyter, and seeing if there is any change in the Traceback?

Comment: When running Jupyter in Anaconda I get a line of text similar to the one above, ending in:

    NameError: name 'StandardError' is not defined
    logout